# Textinputlayout inflate exception in KitKat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-4.4-kitkat, android-textinputlayout, android-api-levels

Here is my following code :

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"

                    android:textColor="@color/text_input_layout"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/text_input_layout"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textview_background"

                        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                       android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The style that has been defined to the activity.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Manifest Code :

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

I have tried a lot of examples from stackoverflow but did not work on Android Os KITKAT(API 17). Apps minimum target is 17.
I get the following runtime error only on Kitkat.

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #138: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

If anyone could help thanks in advance.

Comment: what inside line 138 , this error mean he cant inflate view in run time in this version so show me what inside this line

Comment: > line 138 is the first line of the code.    i.e.      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: try remove this line app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"

Comment: Nope still the same problem. Maybe it is because the layout is not supported in android os version lower than lollypop (5.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to face in trouble with old version, make sure you don't use any vector image and reference it by old way `android:src`, use `app:srcCompat` instead .

Use appcompat view instead old views.

Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` instead of `EditText`.

Update your support library to latest version.

**UPDATE**

Make sure your ActivityName extend **AppCompatActivity** not **Activity** or **FragmentActivity** (by the way when using AppCompatActivity in the run time converted to AppCompat Views).

Comment: The issues is not with the EditText it is with **TextInputLayout** which works fine on Lollypop and above versions. @MinaFawzy . Maybe this line is a problem  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" `

Comment: _Also I am not using any vector images_

Comment: did you use activity or AppCompatActivity

Comment: This is what I have used `public class CustomerActivity extends BaseActivity` and `public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity`  **I will not be changing this code at all**

Comment: change FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity this will fix your issue

Comment: I cannot use AppcombatActivity because that will make me change the theme that i have used i.e. `Theme.Holo.Light`

Comment: use Theme.AppCompat.Light instead